# Fetch new events on every call fullcalendar or refresh fullcalendar events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

so there is a list of doctors and against each doctor there is an anchor saying see appointments etc. When user i click on it, it opens a popup and shows me fullcalendar with events. The thing is for different users it shows the same calendar events. What i think is happening is, the fullcalendar is rendered once and after that i need to refetch the events or something. I've tried this but no luck. Someone please help me.

html

```
foreach($docs as $doc){
   <a href="#" class="doc-calendar" data-id="{{ $doc->id }}" id="see-doc-cal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#doc-cal" >See Doctor Calendar</a> 
}
```

main.js

```
// Getting the doctor ID to know which doctor is clicked
$(document).on("click",".doc-calendar",function(){
    var doctorID = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $("#doctor-id").attr('data-id',doctorID);
});

// See Doctor Appointments Calendar
$("#doctor-calendar").fullCalendar({
    events : function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url : "/dms/GetCalEvents",
            data: {start: start.unix(),end: end.unix(),docID:$('#doctor-id').attr('data-id')},
            dataType : "JSON",
            success: function(result){
                var events = [];
                for(var i = 0;i < result.length; i++) {
                    console.log(result[i]['count']);
                    events.push({
                        title: result[i]['count']+" Appointments",
                        start: result[i]['date']
                    });
                }
                callback(events);
            }
        });
    },
    height: 300
});

// Rendering the above created modal
$('#doc-cal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    //$("#doctor-calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    $("#doctor-calendar").fullCalendar('render');
});
```

Comment: does "user" = "doctor" in your application? You mention it shows the same events for each "user", but there's nothing in your code regarding users. If you mean doctors,then yes you need to run the refetch events method after you re-render it. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/

Comment: Yeah i know i have to run refetchEvents but where, i write refetch before render, it gives me some clone error.

Comment: what error, _exactly_? If you want some help with it you'll have to say precisely what the problem is. Or alternatively why not write it after the render statement instead? Presumably it works if you do that?